# Ignore a specific folder where ever it occurs throughout the project (even if the folder is created in the future) in .gitignore

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I want git to ignore __ pycache__ folder in django. As and when I am creating new apps, this folder "__ pycache __" will be created in the new apps, but I want them to be ignored automatically , instead of mentioning the path for each __ pycache __ folder in every app.

So how do I write in .gitignore so that it ignores the folder named, "__ pycache __" inside the entire project directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add below line in .gitignore

```
__pycache__
```

Comment: Adding : ***/__pycache__/*   .Will also do the trick...!
Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @100rabh: `**/__pycache__` is in a theoretical sense more expensive as it means "first match all the stuff before `__pycache__` (but practically speaking, it's really the same). The more important part is the trailing slash: `__pycache__` will also ignore a *file* named `__pycache__`, while `__pycache__/` will only ignore files *within* something named `__pycache__`.

Comment: @torek, yes , makes perfect sense. Thanks for your input.